# Netlogo: produce a list of items in which each item is a list whose number of members equals its index

Tags: list, netlogo, nested-lists

I need to produce a list in which each item represents a (nested) list whose number of members equals its index, in other words, I should make the following list:

```
[[] [0] [0 1] [0 1 2] [0 1 2 3]]
```

I understand that I should use n-values to do so, but I got stuck with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. The +2 is to consider the empty list and including the upper bound.

```
to-report indexed-list [some-size]
   report n-values (some-size + 2) [n-values ? [?]]
end
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but I'm not sure that the `+ 2` is a good idea: it implies that, e.g., `length indexed-list 5 = 7`, which I find counterintuitive.

Comment: Mattsap, nice answer. Nicolas, I don't see how +2 is a bad idea as the length of the resulting list actually will be 2 greater than the input value. Or am I missing something...